# OSError: [ERRNO 2] micro:bit

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

I am trying to rickroll someone with a microbit (in the python editor) but when I try to run the code, an error message says :OSError: [ERRNO 2]
Here Is the source code:

```
import audio

# read the files from the microbit filesystem
def read_frame(f_list, frame):
    for file in f_list:
        ln = file.readinto(frame)
        while ln:
            yield frame
            ln = file.readinto(frame)

# craete a function to open and play each file in turn
def play_file(f):
    with open(f + "-01.raw", "rb") as file1, \
         open(f + "-02.raw", "rb") as file2, \
         open(f + "-03.raw", "rb") as file3, \
         open(f + "-04.raw", "rb") as file4:
        f_list = [file1, file2, file3, file4]
        audio.play(read_frame(f_list, frame), wait=True)


# Allocate memory outside the interrupt
frame = audio.AudioFrame()
ln = -1
file = 1

# play the files
play_file("robot")
```

the 4 audio files i am using go for about roughly 1 second each because the sample code that I got this from is unchanged, I only changes the files: not the names, and I assume not the length (roughly)

Comment: error no 2 means that the file doesn't exist. Would you mind showing us the file structure?

Comment: Hi @OuterSoda, I don't know how to provide you a file structure as it is in the micropython editor(I am fairly new to this programming language)

Comment: Have you uploaded the `robot-01.raw`, `robot-02.raw`, `robot-03.raw`, and `robot-04.raw` to the editor?

Comment: yes I have but It Still Does not seem to be working